# Java: How do I change the font size of a JRadioButton?

Tags: java, radio-button

How do I change the font size of a JRadioButton (in Java)?
I just want to make the text 24px instead of the default so that it matches the label.

Here's a link to a picture of my window...
(I don't have enough reputation to post the image directly...)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z60kN.png

And here's a snippet of my code...

```
    // question 1: make the labels / radio buttons / buttons / rows
    JLabel q1 = new JLabel("Question 1: 2 + 4");
    q1.setFont (q1.getFont ().deriveFont (24.0f));
    final JRadioButton q1a1 = new JRadioButton("5");
    final JRadioButton q1a2 = new JRadioButton("6");
    final JRadioButton q1a3 = new JRadioButton("7");
    final JRadioButton q1a4 = new JRadioButton("8");
    JButton q1go = new JButton("Go");
    JButton q1exit = new JButton("Exit");
    JPanel question = new JPanel();
    JPanel answers = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    question.setLayout(new BoxLayout(question, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    answers.setLayout(new BoxLayout(answers, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    buttons.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttons, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    // add everything to the rows
    question.add(q1);
    answers.add(q1a1);
    answers.add(q1a2);
    answers.add(q1a3);
    answers.add(q1a4);
    buttons.add(q1go);
    buttons.add(q1exit);

    // add the rows
    add(question);
    add(answers);
    add(answers);
    add(answers);
    add(answers);
    add(buttons);

    // group the radio buttons
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(q1a1);
    group.add(q1a2);
    group.add(q1a3);
    group.add(q1a4);
```

Thanks in advance!

-HewwoCraziness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already done it.
You want the label to have as same font size as Jlabel right. Then you can simply do that by

```
 q1a1.setFont(q1.getFont()); //assign the label's font to radiobutton's font
```

or do the same way you've done it for label

```
  q1a1.setFont(q1a1.getFont().deriveFont(24.0f));
```